# Error using bees with machineguns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-testing

I have tried to use beeswithmachineguns for loadtesting a site but with little success.  There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040859/bees-with-machine-gun-using-amazon-free-tier) but the error I receive is slightly different.

I use the following to start the bees.

```
bees up -s 1 -k Bees-West -g SWARM
```

The error I am getting is related to the groupId being empty but I am passing that value in with -g SWARM... or so I thought. My setup uses the us-west-2 region, which I have in my .boto file as noted in the linked post.

```
Connecting to the hive.  
Attempting to call up 1 bees.  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/bees", line 5, in <module>
    main.main()  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beeswithmachineguns/main.py", line 127, in main parse_options()  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beeswithmachineguns/main.py", line 111, in parse_options  
    bees.up(options.servers, options.group, options.zone, options.instance, options.login, options.key)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beeswithmachineguns/bees.py", line 104, in up  
    placement=zone)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 618, in run_instances  
    return self.get_object('RunInstances', params, Reservation, verb='POST')  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 699, in get_object  
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code><Message>Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>bd1c6bcb-875f-4294-af64-84853b5b258a</RequestID></Response>
```

Comment: You need to be sure to use the correct combination of subnet (-v) and security group (-g).

Comment: Are the instances bees utilizes ones I have setup or are they created dynamically?

Comment: I have an instance in us-west-2a, but the error I get when attempting to run bees is  "Invalid availability zone: [us-west-2a]"

Comment: I don't see subnet(-v) listed as a parameter in the bees help, only zone (-z)  is that the parameter you are referring to?

Comment: The up command has a -v (or --subnet) option for "The vpc subnet id in which the instances should be launched. (default: None)." The bees are dynamically launched. Not sure why you see issues with us-west-2a.

Comment: I suspect I am running in to the outdated installation instructions noted here:  https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns/issues/106.  I will try uninstalling from pip and start fresh from source.

Comment: @MarcusF if that solves it, please post here. If it doesn't, please post your most recent error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure that the group "SWARM" is present in AWS by Clicking on Ec2->Security groups at the left side->check the group name.